# Why is irexec from LIRC not working properly on boot?

Tags: systemd, lirc

I built `LIRC` from source and got it installed. It's running as a `systemd` service on boot and works great. I can run `irw` and it displays the expected output. I can run `ircat` and it shows what is supposed to be run on the `config` line of the `lircrc` configuration file.

The problem I'm having is `irexec`. When I run it from the shell it works fine. When I run it manually by running `systemctl start irexec.service` it works fine. As soon as I reboot and it's supposed to start automatically, and it does, but it does not run my command; it does absolutely nothing. There's not even any error messages in the logs.

The weird thing is that if I restart `irexec.service` after boot, after it was already started, it works fine and runs my command perfectly. Any clue why this is happening?

**This is the irexec.service file**

```
[Unit]
Description=LIRC command handler
After=network.target
Wants=lircd.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/irexec /etc/lirc/lircrc

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The `irexec.service` does always start after the `lircd.service` is already running.

**EDIT** I'm using LIRC 0.9.4-devel

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue but in reverse,

Changing the `irexec.service` file and using the `systemctl` commands does not seem to work to start and stop the service. **A full reboot is needed.**

**You seem to have forgotten the --daemon option.**

This is my `irexec.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=IR Remote irexec config .lircrc loaded on startup
After=lircd.service
Wants=lircd.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/irexec --daemon $HOME/.lircrc
Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably obvious, but I tried all the answers here and elsewhere, and none worked in getting systemctl to start and keep irexec running after boot.  I solved the issue by purging and reinstalling lirc, then recopying my custom made config files to the /etc/lirc folder.  I wish I had tried this first.  It would have saved a lot of time.

```
sudo apt purge lirc
sudo apt install lirc
#then recopy your custom config files 
#irexec.lircrc goes in /etc/lirc/ 
#remote.conf files go in /etc/lirc/lircd.conf.d/
```

Answer (score 0):

What did the trick for me was enabling the irexec service doing a

```
sudo systemctl enable irexec
```

I did not need the --deamon option in the irexec.service that @The Demz needed.

I just submitted a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/raspbian/+bug/2006996) so irexec runs after lircd (after:lircd).